# How to use count() function in xpath of selenium?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

Using `findElements()` and `size()` methods we can get the count.
But I want to extract the count using count() function in the xpath.

Will the count function return an integer value?

Suppose,
My xpath is `(//input[@id='stack'])[3]` and there are 3 matching nodes with `//input[@name='hai']`

Can I modify my xpath like below?

```
(//input[@id='stack'])[count(//input[@name=''hai])]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if

```
count(//input[@name='hai'])
```

evaluates to

```
3
```

then

```
(//input[@id='stack'])[count(//input[@name='hai'])]
```

will select the same nodes as

```
(//input[@id='stack'])[3]
```

would select.

However, your intent is quite unclear, especially given that

- `//input[@id='stack']` will select all of the `input` elements with
  an `id` attribute value of `'stack'`.  Usually `id` attribute values
  are unique across the document, so usually this would select only a
  single element.
- `(//input[@id='stack'])[count(//input[@name='hai'])]` assumes that there are at least as many `input` elements id'ed as `'stack`' as there are `input` elements named `'hai'` -- an odd assumption.

Comment: @Mr.O: Of course it still works.  Whatever problem you're having is unclear from your comment.  Post a new ***question*** with a [mcve] illustrating exactly how what happens differs from what you expect should happen.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I was able to find the issue in the code, the xpath in the count was missing a '/'. Sorry for the vague question. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

`driver.findElements()` returns a List of WebElements, and `.size()` returns the integer size of a list, so I think youd be better off doing the following:

```
int myCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<Your Xpath Here>")).size();
```

This will get you the count of elements on your page that match your xpath input